# Reading a YAML file, changing it and writing it to a file keeping indentation

Tags: bash, shell, yaml

I'm changing a line within a YAML File and redirecting the string I just created for another file. However, the text is not indented as YAML expects.

Basically, I'm doing this:

```
mapfile -t  lines_array < "$input_file_yaml"

for line in "${lines_array[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$line" == "text" ]]; then
                
                 line="other text"
                
        fi
        novo_array+="$line"
done
echo "$novo_array" > novo_compose.yaml
```

Comment: You can do it with sed: `sed 's/^text$/other text/' $input_file.yaml > novo_compose.yaml`

Comment: Add your yaml file to your question (no comment here).

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is iterating over the lines in the input file, changing those that match, and then *concatenating all the lines into a single variable*, with no line separators, and printing that (single) line.

There are a number of ways to do what you want

- put explicit newlines into the string you're creating:

  ```
  novo_array+="$line$'\n'"
  ```
- create novo_array as an actual array rather than a string:

  ```
  novo_array+=("$line")
  ```

  then you can iterate over that array outputting each line:

  ```
  for line in "${novo_array[@]}" do
      echo "$line"
  done > novo_compose.yaml
  ```
- don't slurp everything into memory (arrays/strings) and instead work with streams.  Your code could be:

  ```
  while IFS= read line; do
      if [[ "$line" == "text" ]]; then
          line="other text"
      fi
      echo "$line"
  done < "$input_file_yaml" > novo_compose.yaml
  ```

however, if the transformation you want can be done by sed or awk, those tools are likely to be much more efficient than this.